# How to get rid of floating point in racket?

Tags: racket

I have this expression:

```
 (floor (sqrt 2))
```

Which evaluates to:

```
 #i1.0
```

How do I get rid of the floating point bit and have it produce just 1, how do I convert it to integer type. I looked at documentation but found nothing. Thanks.

Comment: `inexact->exact`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways, as @Alexis pointed out [`inexact->exact`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/number-types.html?q=inexact-%3Eexact#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._inexact-~3eexact%29%29) will do it. But given your use of `floor`, there is an even easier solution, [`exact-floor`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=exact-floor#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmath..rkt%29._exact-floor%29%29), provided by `racket/math` (which is included by default in `#lang racket` programs).

This function has the same semantics as floor, with the one exception that it produces an exact number, rather than an inexact number.

```
> (floor 1.2)
1.0
> (exact-floor 1.2)
1
```

Of course, its important to note that since `+inf.0` and `+nan.0` (and related variants) are only floating point numbers and have no exact analog, you won't be able to cast those:

```
> (floor +inf.0)
+inf.0
> (exact-floor +inf.0)
; exact-floor: contract violation
;   expected: rational?
;   given: +inf.0
; [,bt for context]
```

Basically, the `floor` function operates over `real?` numbers, while `exact-floor` operates over `rational?` ones. However, you will still get that same limitation if you go the inexact->exact route.